# Experimenting I seem to have mixed up Unity and Gnome desktop 3 and would like only one of them

Tags: unity, compiz

When I start my ubuntu 15.04 machine i first get the gnome foot, then all is working fine with Unity, except:

- I can hardly read the top of windows because white on light grey is hard to read.
- Gedit looks different ( no more regular top menu, etc,..)

I would like to have only Unity or Gnome desktop 3, can somebody help? Thanks

I've tried commands like:

```
1494  setsid unity
 1495  unity --reset-icons
 1496  unity
 1497  sudo service lightdm restart
 1498  unity --reset-icons
 1499  sudo service lightdm restart
 1500  sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
 1501  unity-tweak-tool  --reset-unity
 1502  ccsm
 1503  sudo unity-tweak-tool  --reset-unity
 1504  rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity
 1505  reboot
 1506  sudo reboot
 1507  rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/jo ~.compiz*
 1508  sudo rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/jo ~.compiz*
 1509  sudo reboot
 1510  killall gnome-panel
 1511  gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel
 1512  killall gnome-panel
 1513  gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
 1514  compiz --replace
 1515  rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/jo ~.compiz*
 1516  sudo unity-tweak-tool  --reset-unity
 1517  sudo service lightdm restart
 1518  sudo apt-get lubuntu-desktop
 1519  sudo apt-get xubuntu-desktop
 1520  sudo apt-get unity
 1521  unity display:0  --reset
 1522  killall gnome-panel
 1523  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 1524  sudo apt-get update
 1525  sudo reboot
 1526  sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
 1527  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
 1528  sudo reboot
 1529  sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
 1530  sudo apt-get install gnome-session
 1531  sudo apt-get install unity
 1532  sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
 1533  rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/jo ~.compiz*
 1534  sudo rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/jo ~.compiz*
 1535  sudo rm -rf gnome .gnome2 .gconf gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dbrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
 1536  unity display:0  --reset
 1537  sudo service lightdm restart
 1538  lsb_release -d
 1539  getconf LONG_BIT
 1540  echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
 1541  gnome-shell --version
 1542  apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version
 1543  gedit
 1544  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1545  apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 1546  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 1547  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
 1548  sudo apt-get update
 1549  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1550  sudo apt-get update
 1551  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

 1580  dpkg -l|grep ppa-purge
 1581  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1582  sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
 1583  sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 1584  sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1585  sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
 1586  sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: It seems youd do it... what is your problem now?

Comment: What desktop do you want ? From the commands you entered you have even more desktops installed like lxde and xfce, I highly recommend you don't just enter random commands if you don't know what they do, most of these have no relevance to what you want to achieve. First run this in terminal  ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/  and add all the output to your question so we can see exactly how many desktops are installed, then we can work on removing them.

Comment: total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 235 Mar 20 14:43 gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 232 Mar 20 14:43 ubuntu.desktop                                                                        I'm fine with either, let's say i want Unity only.    (And I'm for sure not good at this, but installing the other desktops seemed to have helped me bring back  a "visual desktop")