# How to completely restore default desktop environment in ubuntu 14.04 lts after installing and removing gnome desktop environment.

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, compiz

I got a mix of icons and windows display between gnome and unity. I have follow the steps in other forums with that explain how to remove gnome and restore unity, but that did not work as I expect.

This are some of the forums I followed with no success:

[How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/

[Unity default settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593081/unity-default-settings)

[Experimenting I seem to have mixed up Unity and Gnome desktop 3 and would like only one of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620995/experimenting-i-seem-to-have-mixed-up-unity-and-gnome-desktop-3-and-would-like-o)

Answer (score 8):

Completely remove the GNOME desktop and reinstall the Unity desktop from a virtual console.

Boot the PC - on login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
sudo reboot
```

Although restarting the system isn't strictly necessary, it nevertheless is recommended to do so.

Comment: is this still valid on stock 16.04/16.10 ?

Comment: @ScottStensland Generally spoken, yes, it should still work ... but do I recommend to go this way ? No, because some things might not work 100 % perfectly afterwards - I generally recommend to install and use only that one desktop environment which comes as default (Ubuntu with Unity or Ubuntu GNOME with GNOME). :)

Comment: @cl-netbox, and what about 17.04? :) I agree that doing such things is not cool, but sometimes Unity is messed after such experiments and need to be restored.

Comment: BTW, `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` command helped, without purging GNOME.